# Uncaught (in promise): The message port closed before a response was received

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, express, mean-stack

So before the question I wanna point out that the only thing I could find on this issue was on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154963/promise-error-the-message-port-closed-before-a-reponse-was-received). This issue suggest that this was an issue with wappalyzer, and it was fixed in version 4.0.1. however I am using wappalyzer version 5.1.4 and is up to date with this.

---

I am building a web-app based on the MEAN-stack, everything worked as intended for a long time, until this error kept poping up in my google-chrome console:

[image: console snapshot]

Everytime i would click in my app header, and use my front-end routing to load up different components / modules this error appears, however I dont see any issue with what the web-app presents to me (it's not like I am missing data)

More details on the error:
[image: error description]

I have no idea whats going on, or where this issue comes from.

Comment: It seems like the error is coming from one of your extensions. Can you try and temporarily disable them and see if the issue is caused by one of them?

Comment: Hmm you are right, disabled all - the issue not there.. By enabling one at a time i have discovered the failing extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a failing plugin.

Disable all plugins, and enable them one at a time to find failing chrome extensions.

In this case it was the wappalyzer extension.

Comment: You can verify this the case by running google chrome via commandline with the `--user-data-dir=someotherdir` flag  (which will trick chrome into launching without your settings, and thus be a "fresh" or "bare" version of chrome